# Not able to access EKS LoadBalancer external IP (link) of Mongo Express service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, mongo-express

I am trying to deploy Moongo Express - MongoDB on EKS cluster. I have running pods of MongoDB and MongoExpress on EKS cluster. I have created internal service for MongoDB and external service for MongoExpress. Following is the description of my `mongo-express-service`:

[image]

How do I access the given url? I tried using the URL in browser (http://url:8081) but no output. It says site can't be reached. I have tried similar experiment on minikube. In `minikube` it generates and IP with port number which is accessible through the browser and I get mongo-express UI on the screen. In `minikube` I use following command to run:

```
minikube service mongo-express-service
```

What command I have to run to get it running in case of aws url? This is my first week of learning Kubernetes. I am probably missing something major here. Please let me know what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I am stuck on the same issue ...

Comment: Unfortunately no. For some reason I stopped working on it.